# How to add comments form to frontend in Django?

Tags: django, comments

I wanna add comments form to my Django project. I've added successfully my Comments app to Django admin panel and everything works well in the admin panel. I don't know how to show the comments form on the frontend and that form to be usable by the users.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post= models.ForeignKey(Tellmeyourstory,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='comments')
user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
email = models.EmailField()
body = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

def __str__(self):
    return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

views.py

```
def detail(request,stories_id):
    stories=get_object_or_404(Tellmeyourstory, pk=stories_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'stories': stories})
```

Comment: You define a `ModelForm` (or at least a form), and render the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use modelform for this purpos

```py
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

in you view import above commentform

```
def index(request):
    form = CommentForm()
    context = {'form' : 'form'}
    return render(requset, 'path/to/html', context)
```

in your html simply pass the form like this

```
{{ form }}
```